# SSRS exceptions Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. and AspNetSessionExpiredException

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

Within my asp.net application I have a reportview that connects to the ssrs endpoint when running reports with a large number of parameters (select all option in parameter list) I receive the following exception being thrown

```
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
```

I have seen a number of blogs as well postings here that reference a security patch applied by MS as the contributing cause to this which limits the number of items you can have in a collection to 1000.

I have also seen suggestions to add an appSettings tag within the web.config file for the wcf hosting service located at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer` and add the following entry

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="20000" />
  </appSettings>
```

I have tried this suggestions with no luck. The server running sql2008r2 does not have either of the security updates mentioned and adding the appSettings value to either web.config (config for the ssrs management site or the endpoint) do not have any impact on the exception. I have even increased the value (100000) in the event I had more that 20k items.

My second thought was that the packet size on the wsHttp request may be to large and I need to increase that as well.

**Update**
After digging around some more I have found that I am on the right track. The above was a partial solution according to MS entry [KB2661403](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2661403) The MaxCollectionKey was only part of the entry. The second piece is the serialization of the parameters a second entry needs to be added to the appSettings section

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="1000" />
```

As I started thinking about this I was also incorrect in where this needed to be entered. It did not need to be entered on the SSRS endpoints web.config but on the site hosting the report viewer control. Adding those two entries to the web.config has resulted in the objects being passed across successfully. Now the SSRS system is returning an ASP.NETSessionTimeOut Exception so I need to try to extend this timeout to see if I can get data back on large queries.

Does anyone have any suggestions or recommendations?

-Cheers

Comment: I think you should step back and redesign this report so it does not require so many parameter values to be passed and also runs within the timeout period. Those two issues are often related - sending thousands of parameter values creates a difficult query plan.

Comment: @MikeHoney yes I agree but product mgmt has deemed it otherwise regardless of my suggestions (lol)

Comment: Gotta love managers that tell IT how to do their jobs. Makes you wonder why they hire experts when they won't listen to them. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can't always re-design the report-- the customer wants when the customer wants.

That said, we were running in to this error quite a bit for an increasing number of reports with large datasets for cascading parameters. We had some reports with multiple parameters with over 1500 values in the drop-down. The solutions described above worked for some but did not work for others. That's when a colleague (Pranay Papishetty) came up with a great fix (I am leaving all of field names as they are instead of swapping out for a generic description. You should still be able to get the point):

Fix for the subscriptions issue with POS_08:

The report POS_08 has a parameter with label Organization Unit: which has drop down values close to 1500. This report also has several other parameters with considerable count of drop down values for each parameter, which created as issue in setting up subscriptions on the report. With a high amount of parameter drop down values, even after making some architectural changes to the report server the issues was not solved.

I came up with a kind of parameter masking in the datasets. Normally to pass Organization Units to the main dataset query we use the following filter in the main query in the where clause

```
dbo.vw_orgunit.orgunit in @orgunit
```

(@OrgUnit is the parameter which passes Organization Units to the query.)

Instead of using the above filter for Organization Unit, I used a modified one as below:

```
((dbo.vw_orgunit.Orgunit IN ((SELECT item
FROM   [DW_Master].[dbo].fn_Split (@orgunit_d, ','))))
OR (@orgunit_d) IN ('All Org Units'))
```

The dataset corresponding to the parameter Organization Unit is also modified as follows to add a value “All Org Units” to the drop down values.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
       [OrgUnit] AS [OrgUnit_Code], 
       [OrgUnitDescription] AS [OrgUnit_Desc], 
       ([OrgUnit] + ' - ' + [OrgUnitDescription]) AS [OrgUnit_Label]
FROM dbo.vw_DimOrgUnit
WHERE (
        [OrgLevelAgency] = '73' 
        AND [OrgLevelFiscalYear] IN ( @FiscalYear )
        AND ([OrgLevel_1] + ' - ' + [OrgLevel_1_Description]) IN ( @OrgLevel_1_Label )
        AND ([OrgLevel_2] + ' - ' + [OrgLevel_2_Description]) IN ( @OrgLevel_2_Label )
        AND ([OrgLevel_3] + ' - ' + [OrgLevel_3_Description]) IN ( @OrgLevel_3_Label )
      ) OR [OrgUnitSKey] = '-1' OR ( [OrgUnit] = '5117' AND [OrgUnitFiscalYear] = '2013' /* A Special Case*/ )

UNION
SELECT '' , '', '(Blank)'
UNION
SELECT 'none' , 'none', 'None'
UNION 
SELECT '-100','All Org Units','All Org Units'
ORDER BY [OrgUnit]
;
```

This way when users want to select all Organization Units, they can just select “All Org Units”, instead of selecting and passing the whole drop down values to the query.
This reduces the execution time of the report and increases the performance of the query. After all the changes were implemented the subscriptions were also set up successfully.